# In bridge game, North and South have 9 spades between them. Find the probability that the 4 spades held by the East-West pair split 3-1

Tags: probability

I tried to do like this,

I think 4 spades held by the East-West pair split 3-1, that is, East has 3 and West has 1, or vice versa. 
First North partner combination is :

$$ 
 C(4,3) + C(4,1) + C(4,2) = 4 + 4 + 3 = 11
    $$

Bu it is not true I guess.

Comment: If 1-3 and 3-1 are both valid, then we have $$\frac{\binom43+\binom41}{2^4}.$$ Do you see why?

Comment: @AndrewChin:  this is close but not exact.  You have not accounted for how many non-spades each hand has.  It gives $\frac 12$.  Compare my answer.

Comment: You're right, I thought it was the same thing as flipping 1 or 3 heads out of 4 coins.

Comment: Probabilities cannot be greater than $1$.  You need to divide by the number of cases.  Why do you have $C(4,2)$ in there?  We only want cases where somebody has $1$ or $3$ spades.  Finally, $C(4,2)=6$

Answer (score 1):

You have $26$ cards to distribute, four of which are spades.  The chance for West to have three spades is $\frac {{4 \choose 3}{22 \choose 10}}{26 \choose 4}$ because you choose three of the spades to give him and ten of the other cards.  The idea is the same for West having one spade.  The total is then 
$$\frac {\left({4 \choose 3}{22 \choose 10}+{4 \choose 1}{22 \choose 12}\right)}{26 \choose 4}=\frac{286}{575}$$